# multiple custom select elements don't behave correctly

Tags: javascript, css

1. List item

I created a custom select element on my page. I created a loop that goes through all of them and assigns the EventListeners needed. But for some reason, once I have more than one object, the event listeners are all assigned to the last object. I must be doing something wrong with the parameters.

loop through the objects and assign them the event listeners.

```js
let customSelect = document.querySelectorAll(".custom-select");
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  var selectBtn = customSelect[i].querySelector(".select-button");
  var selectedValue = customSelect[i].querySelector(".selected-value");
  var optionsList = customSelect[i].querySelectorAll(".select-dropdown li");

  // Toggle dropdown visibility when button is clicked
  selectBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    customSelect[i].classList.toggle("active");
  });

  // Handle option selection
  for (var x = 0; x < optionsList.length; x++) {
    optionsList[x].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      selectedValue.textContent = this.textContent;
      customSelect[i].classList.remove("active");
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.select-button {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0.675em 1em;
  border: 1px solid #caced1;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.selected-value {
  text-align: left;
}

.arrow {
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 6px solid #000;
  transition: transform ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.select-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #caced1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.select-dropdown:focus-within {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(94, 108, 233, 0.6);
}

.select-dropdown li {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  align-items: center;
}

.select-dropdown li label {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.select-dropdown::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 7px;
}

.select-dropdown::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.select-dropdown::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.select-dropdown li:hover,
.select-dropdown input:checked~label {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.select-dropdown input:focus~label {
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
}

.select-dropdown input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.custom-select.active .arrow {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.custom-select.active .select-dropdown {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

```html
<div id="newmatpe" class="custom-select">
  <button class="select-button">
      <span class="selected-value" id="a1"> habadaba</span>
      <span class="arrow"></span>
    </button>
  <ul class="select-dropdown">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="radioa1" name="newmatpe" />
      <label for="radioa1">shubi</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="radioa2" name="newmatpe" />
      <label for="radioa2">dubi</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="radioa3" name="newmatpe" />
      <label for="radioa3">Bubi</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="radioa4" name="newmatpe" />
      <label for="radioa4">dubi</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="radioa5" name="newmatpe" />
      <label for="radioa5">FM2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="radioa6" name="newmatpe" />
      <label for="radioa6">AM1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="radioa7" name="newmatpe" />
      <label for="radioa7">Really</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="radioa8" name="newmatpe" />
      <label for="radioa8">cool</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="radioa9" name="newmatpe" />
      <label for="radioa9">other</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


</br>
</br>

<div id="existingmatpe" class="custom-select">
  <button class="select-button">
      <span class="selected-value" id="a2">shlala</span>
      <span class="arrow"></span>
    </button>
  <ul class="select-dropdown">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="radiob1" name="existingmatpe" />
      <label for="radiob1">balala</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="radiob2" name="existingmatpe" />
      <label for="radiob2">malala</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="radiob3" name="existingmatpe" />
      <label for="radiob3">talala</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="radiob4" name="existingmatpe" />
      <label for="radiob4">googoo</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="radiob5" name="existingmatpe" />
      <label for="radiob5">gaga</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="radiob6" name="existingmatpe" />
      <label for="radiob6">yalala</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="radiob7" name="existingmatpe" />
      <label for="radiob7">malala</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="radiob8" name="existingmatpe" />
      <label for="radiob8">sdsdsds</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="radiob9" name="existingmatpe" />
      <label for="radiob9">other</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using radio buttons styled as a drop down menu? And I'm getting a message stating that you're using the same ID, 18 time in the same form

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193). When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result? What were the values used in that operation? What was the result? What result was expected? Why? To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and **its linked resources**

Comment: I edited the code and changed the ids, I also changed the way I approach the selectedValue. The problem persist. It seems that all selections are always referenced to selectedValue "a2" instead of to the relevant one. if I set the for loop to only 1 iteration, the first dropbox gets the right value.

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate id attributes in your code. That's the issue.

Comment: I changed it, still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

After the break, you copied/pasted the code from before the break. This ended up reusing the same `id` attributes for each of the elements. Remember: no two elements can have the same `id`, so this is most likely causing an issue. To have multiple elements that can be referred to using the same "name", try using a `class`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the variables defined in your loop are not block-scoped. This means that at the point where you change the value of the dropdown, your `selectedValue` actually changes to the value `selectedValue` of the last item in your nodelist. If you change all your variable assignments to let/const, you'll see that the problem goes away.

Also if you'll indulge me, here's what I think is a slightly better way your code can be written:

```js
const customSelect = this.document.querySelectorAll('.custom-select');

for (let node of customSelect) {
  const selectBtn = node.querySelector('.select-button');
  const selectedValue = node.querySelector('.selected-value');
  const optionsList = node.querySelectorAll('.select-dropdown li');

  // Toggle dropdown visibility when button is clicked
  selectBtn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    node.classList.toggle('active');
  });

  // Handle option selection
  for (let x = 0; x < optionsList.length; x++) {
    optionsList[x].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      selectedValue.textContent = this.textContent;
      node.classList.remove('active');
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.select-button {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0.675em 1em;
  border: 1px solid #caced1;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.selected-value {
  text-align: left;
}

.arrow {
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 6px solid #000;
  transition: transform ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.select-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #caced1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.select-dropdown:focus-within {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(94, 108, 233, 0.6);
}

.select-dropdown li {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  align-items: center;
}

.select-dropdown li label {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.select-dropdown::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 7px;
}

.select-dropdown::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.select-dropdown::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.select-dropdown li:hover,
.select-dropdown input:checked ~ label {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.select-dropdown input:focus ~ label {
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
}

.select-dropdown input[type='radio'] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.custom-select.active .arrow {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.custom-select.active .select-dropdown {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

```html
<div id="newmatpe" class="custom-select">
    <button class="select-button">
        <span class="selected-value" id="a1"> habadaba</span>
        <span class="arrow"></span>
      </button>
    <ul class="select-dropdown">
      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="radioa1" name="newmatpe" />
        <label for="radioa1">shubi</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="radioa2" name="newmatpe" />
        <label for="radioa2">dubi</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="radioa3" name="newmatpe" />
        <label for="radioa3">Bubi</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="radioa4" name="newmatpe" />
        <label for="radioa4">dubi</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="radioa5" name="newmatpe" />
        <label for="radioa5">FM2</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="radioa6" name="newmatpe" />
        <label for="radioa6">AM1</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="radioa7" name="newmatpe" />
        <label for="radioa7">Really</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="radioa8" name="newmatpe" />
        <label for="radioa8">cool</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="radioa9" name="newmatpe" />
        <label for="radioa9">other</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  
  </br>
  </br>
  
  <div id="existingmatpe" class="custom-select">
    <button class="select-button">
        <span class="selected-value" id="a2">shlala</span>
        <span class="arrow"></span>
      </button>
    <ul class="select-dropdown">
      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="radiob1" name="existingmatpe" />
        <label for="radiob1">balala</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="radiob2" name="existingmatpe" />
        <label for="radiob2">malala</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="radiob3" name="existingmatpe" />
        <label for="radiob3">talala</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="radiob4" name="existingmatpe" />
        <label for="radiob4">googoo</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="radiob5" name="existingmatpe" />
        <label for="radiob5">gaga</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="radiob6" name="existingmatpe" />
        <label for="radiob6">yalala</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="radiob7" name="existingmatpe" />
        <label for="radiob7">malala</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="radiob8" name="existingmatpe" />
        <label for="radiob8">sdsdsds</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="radiob9" name="existingmatpe" />
        <label for="radiob9">other</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Nice to hear that your problem got solved @user23654508. Could you mark the answer as correct so that future people can also use it as well?